# Good practice : Methods and Entities

Tags: php, methods, doctrine, entity

I'm using Doctrine for the first time (and without symfony) and I wonder if it's okay to add "classical" methods directly into the entity or if it's more correct to create another class next to it in order to manage all the other methods of this entity?

When I talk about other methods, I mean anything that is not getter and setter or Magic Methods. Like password encoding or any manipulation with the entity's properties.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I think you can create any methods you like but this methods must operate only entity's data. It means that every new method must always use `$this->some_var` and never use singletons, other objects or services etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks !
So you advise me not to use arguments in my methods and only work with entity parameters ?

Comment: Yes. It is a part of `SOLID`. `S` is for [`Single responsibility`](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-1-the-single-responsibility-principle--net-36074). Your entity must has only one reason to change. And this reason is data that represented by it. Also entity uses a [DTO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). So I think that only accessors are accepted.